# JavaCV Fails to Run after successful clean and build

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans, executable-jar, javacv

I have done a project in java ie a motion detection s/w using javaCV libraries. when i debug the code from netbeans it works correctly. It detects motion and make alarms, sending mail etc. But when i clean and build the code, the obtained .jar file is not loading the webcam.
When i open that .jar file, it shows a blank canvas. 
Another information that can i give is, when i clean & bulids, o/p shows some warnings like deprecated API s.

---

```
init:
deps-clean:
Created dir: C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 35 source files to C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\build\classes
C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\src\projectlogin\NewJFrame1.java:7: warning: String is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String;
C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\src\projectlogin\NewJFrame1.java:17: warning: AudioPlayer is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\src\projectlogin\NewJFrame1.java:18: warning: AudioStream is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\src\projectlogin\operation.java:12: warning: AudioStream is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
import sun.audio.AudioStream;
C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\src\projectlogin\NewJFrame1.java:32: warning: String is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    String t;
C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\src\projectlogin\NewJFrame1.java:36: warning: String is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    static String user;
C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\src\projectlogin\NewJFrame1.java:287: warning: AudioStream is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
            AudioStream as = null;
C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\src\projectlogin\NewJFrame1.java:300: warning: AudioStream is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
                as = new AudioStream(in);
C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\src\projectlogin\NewJFrame1.java:312: warning: AudioPlayer is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
            AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\src\projectlogin\NewJFrame1.java:502: warning: String is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    public static void main(String args[]) {
C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\src\projectlogin\operation.java:44: warning: AudioStream is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    AudioStream as;
C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\src\projectlogin\operation.java:109: warning: AudioStream is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
        as = new AudioStream(in);
C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\src\projectlogin\operation.java:220: warning: AudioPlayer is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
                        AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\src\projectlogin\operation.java:232: warning: AudioStream is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
                        as = new AudioStream(in);
C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\src\projectlogin\operation.java:281: warning: AudioPlayer is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
            AudioPlayer.player.stop(as);
C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\src\projectlogin\operation.java:286: warning: AudioPlayer is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
        AudioPlayer.player.stop(as);
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
16 warnings
Copying 15 files to C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\dist
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\build
Copy libraries to C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\dist\lib.
Building jar: C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\dist\projectlogin.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\dist\projectlogin.jar"
jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

Comment: Are you sure NetBeans and your standalone JAR file use the same JDK, the same version of OpenCV, etc?

Comment: @SamuelAudet :  Yes. JDK1.7 & openCV2.2

Comment: Ok, so please try again with the latest versions: JavaCV 0.3 and OpenCV 2.4.3, and let me know if that works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output indicates that you should run it from the command line `java -jar "C:\Users\Anooj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\projectlogin\dist\projectlogin.jar`

If you run it from the dist directory, it will include the libraries required for the project. I suspect that you are trying to run the project without the associate libraries.

Comment: .The library folders are there in my dist folder. But Still when i open the jar file, GUIs are working properly except the camera. Getting a blank canvas without capturing. I tried to run it from command line, but the problem is still there. Is it due to any error with my OpenCV library in my C drive (OS-drive) ?